# CGImage memory leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, memory-leaks, cgimageref

The following code works the way I want it to, but every time I call it, Instruments tells me I have one CGImage memory leak.  I've been having trouble understanding what to release and when.  The following is from the @interface section of my file.

```
CGImageRef depthImageRef;
char *depthPixels;
NSData *depthData;
```

In the next code, I basically alter depthPixels and then store the result in a new depthImageRef.

```
size_t width                    = CGImageGetWidth(depthImageRef);
size_t height                   = CGImageGetHeight(depthImageRef);
size_t bitsPerComponent         = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(depthImageRef);
size_t bitsPerPixel             = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(depthImageRef);
size_t bytesPerRow              = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(depthImageRef);


for (int row = 0; row < height; row += 1) {

    for (int bitPlace = 0; bitPlace < bytesPerRow; bitPlace += 4) {

        CGPoint pointForHeight = CGPointMake((bitPlace/4) - place.x, row - place.y);

        int distanceFromLocation = sqrt(pow(place.x - pointForHeight.x, 2) + pow(place.y - pointForHeight.y, 2));
        int newHeight = blopHeight - (5 - sizeSlider.value)*distanceFromLocation;

        NSInteger baseBitPlace = row*bytesPerRow + bitPlace;

        CGFloat currentHeight = depthPixels[baseBitPlace];
        if (newHeight > currentHeight) {
            depthPixels[baseBitPlace] = newHeight;
        }
    }
}

CGColorSpaceRef colorspace      = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo         = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(depthImageRef);
CGDataProviderRef provider      = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, depthPixels, [depthData length], NULL);

depthImageRef = CGImageCreate (
                               width,
                               height,
                               bitsPerComponent,
                               bitsPerPixel,
                               bytesPerRow,
                               colorspace,
                               bitmapInfo,
                               provider,
                               NULL,
                               false,
                               kCGRenderingIntentDefault
                               );
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
CFRelease(provider);
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
```

I believe the leak is created because I keep creating depthImageRef but never release it.  I've tried putting CGImageRelease(depthImageRef) at various places and setting depthImageRef to nil, and usually when I do this I get crashes.  Thanks!

Comment: You should always release what you create. So you releasing `depthImageRef` is correct. do check if you are referencing the `depthImageRef` after releasing it. Moreover, what is this ???----`>CFRelease(provider);
>CGDataProviderRelease(provider);`  why are you releasing Provider twice ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are recreating depthImageRef multiple times by calling the above code, you are leaking memory by repeatedly creating CGImageRefs and not releasing them.  If you are recreating `dataImageRef` you should release the old image immediately before creating the new one.

```
// works, even if depthImageRef is NULL such as in the initial case.
CGImageRelease(depthImageRef);
depthImageRef = CGImageCreate ( //...
```

Also be sure you are calling `CGImageRelease` in your `dealloc` method and freeing your `depthPixels` buffer in dealloc.  `CGDataProviderRelease` won't release the buffer you pass into it unless you pass a callback to already release that buffer. You don't need the call for `CFRelease(provider)` since you are calling `CGDataProviderRelease(provider)`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you must be turning the depthImageRef back to UIImage somewhere. Like

```
UIImage *depthImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:depthImageRef];
```

Once you have the depthImage you can release depthImageRef. It should not cause any crash.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to make sure is to release the **CGImageRef** once you are done with it's use.

```
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
```

Comment: This is already stated in the accepted answer.